# How to have a JButton insert information into a JTextArea from another classes method? - java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to call information from another classes method, into a JTextArea when you press a JButton.

```
jbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           jtextarea. ???? 

        }

    });
```

I can make it print text if the text is already specified within the action performed and other methods that are specified for jtextarea methods. But I want the text area to return values from other methods in other classes. How can I do this?

More info: I'm getting information from a URL connection, that information is parsed into a string which becomes a company, then there is another class that takes the companies and adds methods for printing. In addition I'm multi-threading the connection for uptodate info. But as these are kinda interacting aspects, I can't just type the information in the jtextarea, I need to call the method to insert the company information. How can I call methods that will deliver values and text into the jtextarea?

Comment: Please try to add more information

Comment: Some where along the line, you're going to need a reference to either the component(s) or the information you want to display. But you've provided little to no context...

Comment: The [JTextArea javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) are just a Google search away and tell you all about every method that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should wrap the `JTextArea` and the Classes you want get the methods from together in another class. If there are multiple different classes and methods, you can create a switch statement within this new class to return the correct method. If this is the case, I would consider redesigning my project to try to prevent the need for such a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Other {

public static String retInfo(){
  return "Some Information";
}

}
```

now do the following in your actionPerformed method

```
jtextarea.setText(Other.retInfo());
```

**you can also do the above by nonestatic public getters but you will have to create an instance of the class Other **